# How do I log the CPU/Network usage for my console app, alternative a unittest in c#

Tags: c#, performance, logging, profiling, cpu

I have profiling and optimizing a set of code. For now I have actually just manual looked at the runtime of a unittest and been looking in Resource Manager in windows.

My unit-test now work and everything is working as it should. I would like to documentate my findings, and need to log the CPU and Network Usage instead of just viewing it myself.

If i can do it directly on my unit-test that would be fine, but there properly are some overhead and therefore i did put the code in a console app instead.

How do i easiest log the CPU / Network usage like the number shown in the Resource Manger in windows 8 (its nicely detailed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution for calculating performance CPU / Memory Address**

1. If you want to do it manually, you can add the "namespace"
   "System.Diagnostic" and use the class "StopWath" that allows you to
   retrieve time to calculate the performance of your applications and
   the time to call your functions.

   Look here to use the class "StopWath" by microsoft example with
   computing performance.
   [StopWatch How to use it ?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

   1. Or else you can also use a fabulous tool called Microsoft **"CLR
      Profiler"** is an application to calculate the performance of your
      application. **Net C # or ASP**. Application complete with visual speech
      on the memory and the time between each call over the management of
      "garbage collector"

   [How use Clr profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx)

   [Download Clr profiler](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/4/2/442d67c7-a1c1-4884-9715-803a7b485b82/clr%20profiler.exe)

**Solution for calculating performance Network traffic**

[You can use the network simulation from visual studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lkruger/archive/2009/06/08/introducing-true-network-emulation-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Or this applications :

[A network sniffer c#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C)

[Network sniffer and connection Analyser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8254/Network-Sniffer-and-Connection-Analyzer)

[sniff web client](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3961/Sniff-Web-Clients-using-ASP-NET)

Comment: Not sure how stopwatch can be used. unless you mean I should figure out how much data it transmit ? Does the CLR profiler log the network usage? Looking over the links as i write.

Comment: Not the clr profiler fails to calculate and analyze network performance .. But I change my answer to add examples of network analysis

Comment: This dont really support my idea of profiling my applicaiton, all these tools to configure and running, it seams easier just to monitor the stuff in windows instead. But thanks for the links

Comment: Do not worry. it is a pleasure